# When click on button hides another button located in other class

Tags: c++, qt, hide, qt5

I have two classes.
The first class called `Widget` and there is a button belongs to it, and the second class called `dialog` and also there is a button belongs to it.
When click on the button(`Open Dialog`) which on widget, shows a window dialog that belong to `dialog class`.

[image]

What I want is, when click on the button that belong to `dialog class` hides the button that belong to `widget class`.

I have tried to do so by using the normal way, but I failed.

```
void Dialog::on_doSomthing_btn_clicked(){
    Widget *widget = new Widget;
    QPushButton *btn = widget->findChild<QPushButton *>("OpenDialog_Btn");
    btn->hide();
}
```

Also I have used the `Signal & Slot` way as the following:

**widget.h**

```
private slots:
    void hideButton();
```

**widget.cpp**

```
void Widget::hideButton(){
    ui->OpenDialog_Btn->hide();
}
```

**dialog.h:**

```
signals:     
    void doHideButton();
```

**dialog.cpp:**

```
void Dialog::on_doSomthing_btn_clicked(){
    Widget *widget = new Widget;
    connect(this, SIGNAL(doHideButton()), widget, SLOT(hideButton()));
    emit doHideButton();
    this->close();
}
```

**How to do so, or what the problem in my code ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `Widget` class every time you press the button. What you should do is connect a signal from your `Dialog` object to a slot of your existing `Widget` object.

Somewhere in your code you are creating an instance of your `Dialog` class. It turns out it's in your `Widget` class. When you create that instance, connect its signal to a slot of your `Widget` object:

```
Dialog dialog;
connect(&dialog, SIGNAL(hideSignal()), this, SLOT(hideSlot()));
```

And emit `Dialog::hideSignal` when you press the button that should hide the other button in the `Widget` object. And inside `Widget::hideSlot` you simply hide the button.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a local instance of `Widget` on stack when the button is pressed. You should either hold a pointer to the object of `Widget` to access it or use signal-slot mechanism. Just use a signal in `Dialog` class which is connected to some slot in the `Widget` class.  when the button is pressed emit the signal and hide the button in the receiving  slot.

Comment: I have used  the pointer way and still does not work, see my code again, I have been updated my question.

Comment: You are making a new instance of `Widget`. You should have a pointer to the existing object which open the dialog.

Comment: Can you give me an example please.

Comment: @thuga: Thanks, I know the member variables, but I want an example to How to make a pointer to the object of Widget to access it, like the `Nejat` said.

Comment: @LionKing That's what he meant. Have a pointer as a member variable so you can use it in all methods of the class. I don't know where you initialize your real `Widget`, but if it's outside of the `Dialog` class, then you should have a `signal` in the `Dialog` class connected to a `slot` in the `Widget` class where you hide the button.

Comment: @thuga: Thank you, for `Signal & Slot` I have used this way, but still does not work fine. please review my code to see if `Signal & Slot` that I used is correct or wrong.

Comment: @LionKing I meant connect a signal from `Dialog` class to a slot in `Widget` class without creating a new instance of `Widget` like you are doing in your code. Where do you create the instance of the `Widget` that is actually shown on the screen?

Comment: @thuga: Please, I want an example to understand everything if it possible.

Comment: @LionKing Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/P25zE3NL). I don't know how and where you create your instances of your `Widget` and `Dialog` classes, but it is important that you connect the signals and slots of the correct instances.

Comment: @thuga: I think your code similar to my code with some little difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62594/discussion-between-thuga-and-lion-king).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but I still think that signals and slots mechanism is better. (as it recommend `Nejat` here and as I recommended this to you later)

Widget.h:

```
public:
    //...
    void hideBut();
```

Widget.cpp:

```
void Widget::hideBut()
{
    ui->pushButton->hide();
}
```

Dialog:

```
//#include "widget.h"
void Dialog::on_doSomthing_btn_clicked(){
     Widget* par = static_cast<Widget*>(parent());
     if(par)
         par->hideBut();
}
```

and:

```
Dialog *mDialog = new Dialog(this);
mDialog->show();
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, your code does not works for me. also I have used the `Signal & Slot` way and also does not work, see my question again, I have been updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent)
{
...
QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("Button To Hide");
connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyWidget::onButtonToHideClicked);
...
}

void MyWidget::onButtonToHideClicked() 
{
QPushButton *btn = (QPushButton*)sender();
btn->hide();
}
...
```

Comment: Can you tell which part you did not understand? If the sender() method, you can get the sender object with sender() method in a slot, in this case, it's the button you clicked, because we connected the clicked signal to the onButtonToHideClicked slot in the constructor. So you can open a new dialog in the slot, and hide the button here as getting its pointer and casting to QPushButton with sender() method

Comment: But I don't want to hide the button which I clicked, I want to hide another button belong to another class, as in the picture displayed in my question.